# Importing data format changed

Tags: excel, vba, delimiter, import-from-excel

I have been designed a script that was working with importing data from a file and then creating relevant table and and charts in the excel.
Unfortunately the data format of the input file changed and now the script gives an error. Although the change is just of the delimiter but changing the delmiter option in the script does not make the script work.
The format of the file is the following:

**Old format:**

Name,"Surname","Email","Company","File Name"

**New format:**

Name;Surname;Email;Company;File Name

The code I am using is the following:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="MyExport", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Khawaja\Desktop\MyExport.csv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=5, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Surname"", type" & _
        " text}, {""Email"", type text}, {""Company"", type text}, {""File Name"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=MyExport;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [MyExport]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "MyExport_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    ActiveSheet.Select
```

In this code, I have changed the delimiter but the error is that it cannot recognize the word Name in the file which means there is something else I need to change

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Eut.png]

The error I get is above in the image.

The old and new files respectively

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nWDQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJesh.png

Comment: Your code is working for me. So, what do you mean with _it cannot recognize the word Name in the file_?

Comment: I edited the post so you see the error. It is not able to read the first colomn that is by the title 'Name'

Comment: This is probanly caused by the fact that the header in your CSV file does not have _Name_  as a header at least that's is one way for me to re-produce this error. Maybe _Name_ contains a white space like a blank or whatever at the end

Comment: I have attached an image of how the first row looks like. Does the inverted commas effect the scenerio? You can see there are no spaces. What do you mean by the header in the CSV file is not Name. Thanks a lot for your help and guidance.

Comment: The header is the first line of the CSV file and the column _Name_ in your CSV file does not contain _Name_. If it contains _'Name_ then you will get the error messsage above. Even a small difference can cause this error. As I do not have your data I can only guess but that's my guess.

Comment: Checked it thorough. The header is absolutely. I think there is a problem with the code in line 2 or 3. Is there any website, defining the format for this code of line?